# How to handle TDatetime in a TJSONObject

Tags: json, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have a TJSONObject from previous processes and need to add a time-based field at a later stage. How would you recommend to do it? Should I add is a number (Double) or convert to string and later back again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON has no concept of date/time values, so you will have to choose for yourself whether you want to add them as strings or numbers.

If you use numbers, I would suggest separating the individual components, eg:

```json
"date": {
  "month": ###,
  "day": ###,
  "year": ###
},
"time": {
  "hour": ###,
  "minute": ###,
  "second": ###,
  "msec": ###
}
```

If you use strings, I would suggest using a format that is easy to parse back out, like ISO-8601, eg:

```json
"date": "YYYY-MM-DD",
"time": "HH:MM:SS.ZZZ"
```

or:

```json
"datetime": "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.ZZZ",
```

Comment: I was rather thinking of something like TJSONNumber(DateTime)...
But I guess I will go for strings...